# How to blink an image each second without changing alpha in Android Animation

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

I want to create an animation where after a single second an image completely appears and disappears. I am trying to create something similar to a flicker effect. I want the image to transition without different being half-visible, so no different alpha values. Right now over one second, the image appears slowly.

```
var mainduration = 1000
var animation: Animation = AlphaAnimation(0.toFloat(), 1.toFloat())
duration =  mainduration.toLong()
interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE
startAnimation(animation)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use view animators, as you are doing here, you would need to create a custom `Interpolator` that implemented your desired algorithm, instead of using `LinearInterpolator`. Alternatively, toggle the visibility of the `ImageView`, perhaps using a `ScheduledExecutorService` for handling the periodic timing.

Comment: Yeah, the easiest fix is probably to create an ``Interpolator`` where ``getInterpolation`` returns 0 if it's <0.5 and 1 otherwise (and don't reverse it)